# Loops with different starting and end points

Tags: complex-analysis

The definition of a loop (in the complex plane) is a path $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$.

I was wondering to what extent can we call a loop a path with $\gamma(0) \neq \gamma(1)$ but with an interval $I = [a, 1]$ such that $\gamma(a) = \gamma(0)$ and $\forall t \in I$ the path just overlaps the "beginning" of the path.

I know it's silly because we could just restrain $\gamma \vert_{[0,a]}$ to get a loop but what happens if we, for example, integrate an holomorphic function over the whole path $\gamma$.

Comment: You can always replace the interval $[a,b]$ with $[0,1]$ by rescaling the and a shift. So for $f:[a,b] \rightarrow [0,1]$ we have $f(x)= (x-a)/(b-a)$ which is invertible. So if we're given a path $\gamma : [a,b]$ we can form $f^{-1} \circ g \circ f$ to define it on $[0,1]$ then convert back to $[a,b]$.